# multiple json file to a single csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scripting

I am trying to convert multiple JSON files and merge them into a single .csv file. All the files has the same keys

```
{
  "1":[
    {
      "bdev":"nvme:0000:60:00.0n1",
      "params":{
        "sequential":true,
        "write":false,
        "io_size":262144,
        "max_cmds":1,
        "test_cycles":100000000,
        "seconds":300
      },
      "state":"completed",
      "date":"2022-07-13 05:37:35",
      "ios_done":1438380,
      "bytes_done":377062686720,
      "cot_ios_issued":1438380,
      "cot_obj_blk_msk":0,
      "cot_start_lba":16,
      "cot_end_lba":3750730309,
      "cot_next_lba":92056336,
      "iops":4794,
      "mbs":1256,
      "latency_min":87,
      "latency_ave":208,
      "latency_max":994910,
      "status":"Success"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried using jsonv using gawk but failed with an error.

```
read_sequential_4096_1.json | jsonv sequential,write,io_size,max_cmd,seconds,iops,mbs,latency_min,latency_ave,latency_max
gawk: /usr/local/bin/.jsonv/json.awk:238: warning: regexp escape sequence `\"' is not a known regexp operator
```

Using JQ

```
$ cat read_sequential_4096_1.json | jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv'
0
jq: error (at <stdin>:30): object ({"bdev":"nv...) is not valid in a csv row
```

Below python code worked but need only these keys `sequential,write,io_size,max_cmd,seconds,iops,mbs,latency_min,latency_ave,latency_max`

```
import pandas as pd 
import os 
 
frame = pd.DataFrame() 
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()): 
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename) 
    if ext == '.json': 
        tmp_frame = pd.read_json(filename) 
        frame = frame.append(tmp_frame, ignore_index=True)  
        frame.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this.

```
import json
import csv
 
with open('json_file_path') as json_file:
    jsondata = json.load(json_file)
 
csv_file = open('write_new_csv_filename', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(data_file)

count = 0
for data in jsondata:
    if count == 0:
        header = data.keys()
        writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
    writer.writerow(data.values())
 
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: only these fields are required from JSON files

sequential,write,io_size,max_cmd,seconds,iops,mbs,latency_min,latency_ave,latency_max

Comment: also wanted this for multiple JSON files